# How to read the logs of the DagFile Processor Process in Airflow?

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I have a python file that generates logs dynamically, reading from a table in a database. I always edit this file blindly because I can't debug the execution of it.

I know Airflow triggers a subprocess to process this file (the `DagFileProcessorProcess`), I just want to be able to read the logs of this process to debug it. I've already tried changing the `logging.dag_processor_log_target` config to stdout and changing the log location as well with `logging.dag_processor_manager_log_location`. Nothing worked, I can just read scheduler logs and task execution logs.

I'm using Airflow 2.2.5, running scheduler + webserver locally.

Comment: Hi! Yeah that is curious you are getting scheduler logs but not dagfileprocessor logs, since they should both be using the [airflow.processor logger](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/dag_processing/processor.py#L135)... is it possible you are using a customized DagFileProcessor class? 
Other than that I might consider upgrading. There was [this change](https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/7363e35c9dbb9860eabf2444307f4d6f8140ab70) made to ensure logs are propagated recently, which could be related to your error. Just some vague-ish ideas

Comment: Hmm my version is 2.2.5 so I might not have that. I have a custom logging_config class though (we use it to provide stdout logs for the k8s cluster and ship logs to GCS), I will try to fiddle with that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set ENV for this to point to the location where you want to see the dag processor log.

`AIRFLOW__LOGGING__DAG_PROCESSOR_LOG_TARGET`

please check docs here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-processor-log-target

Comment: As I commented, I already tried that, didn't work...

Comment: that weird please create GH issue here https://github.com/apache/airflow